# Classic asp and webservices - how to make it work with java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I have taken over an older applikation written in classic ASP, that uses 2 different webservices to post and receive responses from.

Webservice A is done in ASP. It works fine in both IE and Chrome.

Webservice B is done in ASP as well. It works fine in IE, unresponsive in Chrome. I re-did it in Java, but in IE it will give a [Security warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqwam.png) and in Chrome nothing happens. Webservice B also call a webservice on its response.

I would really prefer for the webservice to work in both browsers, without the warning pop-up as that can be really annoying over time.

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why service A works fine, but B does not.

**Webservice A**

```
Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", "http://serviceA?wsdl", False 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "urn:requestA"

SOAPRequest = [XMLRequest]

On Error Resume Next
oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest   

If Err.Number Then 
'Do something
Err.Clear 
Else 
SOAPResponse = oXmlHTTP.responseXML.text

End If 
On Error Goto 0 


If LEN(SOAPResponse) > 0 Then
Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objxml.async = False
objxml.load (oXmlHTTP.responseXML)      

If objxml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
     'handle the error
End If

Set nodeList = objxml.getElementsByTagName("TagName")
SizeofObject = nodeList.length-1
For i = 0 To (SizeofObject)

    'get individual element

Next    

Set oXmlHTTP = nothing 
SOAPRequest = ""
SOAPResponse = ""
```

**Webservice B**

```
Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
oXmlHTTP.open "POST", "http://serviceB?wsdl", False 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" 

SOAPRequest = [XMLRequest]

On Error Resume Next
oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest   

If Err.Number Then 
    'Handle error
    Err.Clear 
Else 
    SOAPResponse = oXmlHTTP.responseText

End If 
On Error Goto 0 


if len(SOAPResponse) > 0 then
    Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    objxml.async = False
    objxml.load (oXmlHTTP.responseXML)      

    If objxml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
         'handle the error
    End If

    Set nodeList = objxml.getElementsByTagName("TagB1")
    SizeofObject = nodeList.length-1

    For i = 0 To (SizeofObject)  

        'get individual elements
        array(i)    = nodeList.item(i).Text

    Next    

    NextRequest(array)
else 
    'handle empty
end if
    Set oXmlHTTP = nothing 
    SOAPRequest = ""
    SOAPResponse = ""


Function NextRequest(inputArray())
If UBound(inputArray)>=0 Then

    For Each ele In inputArray
    Set oXmlHTTP2 = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    oXmlHTTP2.Open "POST", "http://serviceB?wsdl", False 
    oXmlHTTP2.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" 

    SOAPRequest2 =[XMLRequest2]

    On Error Resume Next
    oXmlHTTP2.send SOAPRequest2   

    If Err.Number Then 
        'Handle
        Err.Clear 
    Else 
        SOAPResponse2 = oXmlHTTP2.responseXML.text
    End If 
        On Error Goto 0 

    If Len(SOAPResponse2) > 0 then

        Set objxml2 = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        objxml2.async = False
        objxml2.load (oXmlHTTP2.responseXML)        

        'Fejlhåndtering af XML
        If objxml2.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
                 'handle the error
        End If

        Set nodeList = objxml2.getElementsByTagName("Tag2")
        SizeofObject = nodeList.length-1

            For j = 0 To SizeofObject
                Response.Write objxml2.getElementsByTagName("Tag2").item(j).Text
            Next 

    End If
    Next

    Set oXmlHTTP2 = nothing 
    SOAPRequest2 = ""
    SOAPResponse2 = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Javascript tag meant to be a Java tag??

Comment: Yes, I've corrected it now

Comment: you have a comment 'handle the error but you're not doing anything there. First step would be to "handle" the error and find out exactly what it is.

Comment: I notice that you're using different versions of msxml in the same script, which sometimes causes problems.  I recommend you use most recent one throughout - ie: `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`  and `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

Comment: Perhaps because you are missing a `SOAPAction` request header on Webservice B?

Comment: Thank you your replies
@JoshMontgomery I left out the bit that handles the error to simplify the snippet. No error has occured yet. The response is fine after you click "ok" to the prompt in IE - but again, in Chrome nothing happens.

Comment: @John I did as you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Lankymart The SoapAction is not necessary, but even when I add it, the response it still the same

Comment: were you able to get this resolved or do you still need assistance with it?